# Margin left and 100% width push float text move beyond the browser edge

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I have the following html:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="text">
  This text float to right
  </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.text {
  float: right;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/mddc/68tgqxpa/4/

The problem is that some of "This text float to right" is pushed beyond the browser edge. How can I use CSS to make the full text display to the browser edge?

The left-margin cannot be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use width of `footer` like this:

```
width: calc(100% - 50px);
```

and there you go! Let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.text {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="text">
    This text float to right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

`.text { margin-right: 50px;}`